# Enable thumb detection on MacBook Pro

Tags: touchpad, macbook, synaptics

I have successfully installed Ubuntu 11.10 and 12.04 on my MacBook Pro 8.1 and now I have issues with my touchpad. I am used to click the button of the pad instead of tapping it to click an item, however the touchpad does not allow me to move the cursor with one finger while having my thumb on the button on the bottom. This is extremely weird and driving me crazy - is there any way to configure Ubuntu or the driver to allow the thumb being on the pad without being recognized? (Maybe by increasing the necessary pressure on it?)

Comment: One of the many reasons I will never buy Apple products. I miss very much the 'nib' pointers of ol' that resided happily betwixt the 'g' and 'h' keys.

Comment: They can be found in Lenovo laptops, however I already got used to the multitouch gestures which can be simulated via Touchégg.

Comment: Indeed, business class laptops are my favorites.

Answer (score 1):

this is one of the new features of ubuntu 12.04 install it and you will be good to go!

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PrecisePangolin/TechnicalOverview/Beta2#ClickPad_support

Comment: This will be included in the final release as stated in the text - let's hope this will be done as promised!

Comment: Wanted to tell you, that this feature isn't enabled yet for me.

Comment: actually after uppgrading to 12.04 myself i realized their "thumb detection is somewhat incomplete.

the new features it supports is:
* not moving mouse pointer unless the touchpad is touched by a finger
* holding down the track pad and dragging/ letting go  to continue to drag over the screen.

It's nice, its better, but it's not enough to match the features in OSX